# Gmail API - Seeing strange German characters using 'raw' output and decoding into utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I have an issues with some encoding when reading emails using the Gmail API.
First i retrieve the email using this:

```
message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id='169481bce75af185', format='raw').execute()
```

After that I use these line to get a string out of it and convert it into mime message:

```
msg_str = str(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'))
mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
```

Then I print what I got:

```
print(mime_msg.get_payload()[0])
```

However I can see some weird characters in the output for example:

```
Gesch=C3=A4ftsf=C3=BChrer
```

In the message header I can see this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

What did I do wrong and how can I get the correct output without the strange characters?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data has been encoded as UTF-8 and then made safe for 7-bit transmission by further encoding as quoted-printable. That is what the message header is telling you. Use `quopri` to undo the quoted-printable and then `.decode` to get Unicode:

```
>>> import quopri
>>> print(quopri.decodestring("Gesch=C3=A4ftsf=C3=BChrer").decode("utf-8"))
Geschäftsführer
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It indeed displays correctly now:

    print(quopri.decodestring(str(mime_msg.get_payload()[0])).decode('utf-8'))

Answer (score 2):

as BoarGules suggested, it displays the characters properly now. Browsing this site also led me to this useful function:

```
def decode_email(msg_str):
    p = Parser()
    message = p.parsestr(msg_str)
    decoded_message = ''
    for part in message.walk():
        charset = part.get_content_charset()
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            part_str = part.get_payload(decode=1)
            decoded_message += part_str.decode(charset)
    return decoded_message
```

Which converts the message string into decoded string display the characted properly.